# Regras de negócio no JSF

Tags: java, java-ee, jsf-2.2, arquitetura-de-software

No JSF onde seria o melhor local para definir as regras de negócio? No modelo, na managed-bean ou ou em uma camada de regras de negócio( tenho bastante relutância em adotar essa última abordagem), ou ainda, implementar tais regras como sendo validadores customizados do JSF? Tenho dúvidas quanto a implementar uma regra de negócio no modelo uma vez que não sei quando esse método seria chamado, já que a bean irá acessar diretamente os sets do modelo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ola.
Não sei se isso seria bem uma resposta porque você poderia utilizar da maneira que achar melhor.
Aqui na empresa onde trabalho temos esta estrutura:

A nossa camada de visão é composta por:

- Página JSF
- Manged Bean (MB)

A nossa regra de negócio é composta por:

- Bisness Controller (BC)

E os controladores são:

- Data Access Object (DAO)

Mas como lhe disse, depende de como você se adaptar em seu negócio!
Abraços

Comment: Também utilizamos assim. E um package com todos os objetos. Uma dificuldade é sempre utilizar o BC para realizar as validações, porém sempre acaba ficando alguma coisa no Bean...Não sei se sou o único que acaba caindo nessa situação.

Comment: Ola, claro que algumas coisas sempre vão acabar caindo no Bean. No meu caso, por exemplo, tenho projetos separados (bibliotecas eu diria), ou seja, um projeto é a camada de visão e a outra é a de regra de negócio. Algumas dependências que eu tenho na camada de visão eu não tenho no negócio, e não teria porque ter apenas para fazer validações... ai faço as validações no Bean mesmo. As validações consideradas padrões eu faço no BC.

Answer (score 1):

O melhor lugar é na camada Service exemplo

- Model (Seus Objetos)
- Controller (Chama seu Service,Evitar o maximo ter if's aqui)
- Service (Onde Fica todas suas Regras de Negócios)
- Dao (Seus Repositorys)

Exemplo :

```
public class LoginController {

     @inject
     private LoginService loginService;
     public void login(Login login)
     {
         loginService.login(login);
     }
}

public class LoginService {

   public boolean login(Login login){
       //todas as Regras feitas aqui!
      if(){
      }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Como o Gilvan disse, existem várias formas de se fazer, aqui na empresa fazemos assim:

- JSF - xhtml
- Managed Bean
- DAO
- Model

Comment: Entendi. Acho que minhas regras mais simples serão transformadas em validadores customizados do JSF. E vou deixar a classe service apenas com métodos que tenham que acessar o banco de dados.